# Amazon SNS signature verification not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, x509, amazon-sns

I am working on Amazon Simple Notification service (SNS) with Liferay. I have subscribed topics to an endpoint and receiving bounce, delivery, complaint objects successfully. But I am struggling with signature verification. I am using the same code given by aws in following url: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html
Do I need any configuration for X509Certificate?

Have also referred this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.https.ca.html. But they have not mentioned where to add it or else I am not able to interpret from the desc given. I can't complete the functionality as this is the crucial part of it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.